# Should/How can I avoid this nested subscription using Angular materials dialog box

Tags: angular, rxjs

I currently have this set up:

```
this.entitiesManagementService.searchAddressEventEmitter$.pipe(switchMap((_) => {
  const formValue = this.addressAttributesSearchForm.getRawValue();
  return forkJoin([
    this.entitiesManagementService.getAddressClassification(new GetAddressClassificationPayload(<payloadValues>))),
    this.entitiesManagementService.searchAddress(new SearchAddressPayload(<payloadValues>))
  ])
})).pipe(this.takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe(([fields, searchResults]) => {
  this.searchResults = searchResults
  this.fields = fields[0].addressFieldDetailDetails;

  const dialogRef = this.modalService.open(SelectAddressModalComponent, {
    data: {
      addresses: this.searchResults,
      fields: this.fields
    }
  })
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(selectedAddress => {
    console.log(selectedAddress)
  })
})
```

I'm wondering if theres a nice way that I can avoid the nested subscription, or whether its truly necessary?

If I understand correctly, the dialogRef.afterClosed() observable will always complete, so there probably isn't a concern with that subscription staying open, but I suppose I should probably avoid the nested subscription.

Can anyone advise on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `switchMap` for this.

```
this.entitiesManagementService.searchAddressEventEmitter$.pipe(
  switchMap((_) => {
    const formValue = this.addressAttributesSearchForm.getRawValue();
    return forkJoin([
      this.entitiesManagementService.getAddressClassification(new GetAddressClassificationPayload(<payloadValues>))),
      this.entitiesManagementService.searchAddress(new SearchAddressPayload(<payloadValues>))
    ]);
  }),
  tap(([fields, searchResults]) => {
    this.searchResults = searchResults
    this.fields = fields[0].addressFieldDetailDetails;
  }),
  switchMap(([fields, searchResults]) => {
    return this.modalService.open(SelectAddressModalComponent, {
      data: {
        addresses: this.searchResults,
        fields: this.fields
      }
    }).afterClosed();
  }).
).subscribe(selectedAddress => console.log(selectedAddress));
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This looks like a very nice clean solution

Answer (score 1):

Your best friend in situations, where you ask yourself "How do I avoid nested subscriptions?" is [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap).

```js
this.entitiesManagementService.searchAddressEventEmitter$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    const formValue = this.addressAttributesSearchForm.getRawValue();
    return forkJoin([
      this.entitiesManagementService.getAddressClassification(new GetAddressClassificationPayload(<payloadValues>))),
      this.entitiesManagementService.searchAddress(new SearchAddressPayload(<payloadValues>))
    ]);
  }),
  this.takeUntilDestroyed(),
  switchMap(([fields, searchResults]) => {
    const dialogRef = this.modalService.open(SelectAddressModalComponent, {
      data: {
        addresses: searchResults,
        fields: fields[0].addressFieldDetails
      }
    })
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }).subscribe(selectedAddress => {
    console.log(selectedAddress)
})
```